# How to count the number of times any 2 elements in a column occur together?

Tags: python, pandas

I need a code that counts the number of times any 2 Titles occur together **under the same Document_Source.**

Here is the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['Dead poet society',
'Before sunrise',
'Finding Dory',
'Blood diamond',
'A beautiful mind',
'Blood diamond',
'Before sunrise',
'The longest ride',
'Marley and me',
'The longest ride',
'Blood diamond',
'Dead poet society',
'Remember me',
'Inception',
'The longest ride',
'Gone with the wind',
'Dead poet society',
'Before sunrise',
'Midnight in Paris',
'Mean girls'],'1Name': ['Julia Roberts',
'Sandra Bullock',
'Emma Stone',
'Anne Hathaway',
'Amanda Seyfried',
'Anne Hathaway',
'Sandra Bullock',
'Reese Witherspoon',
'Jennifer Aniston',
'Reese Witherspoon',
'Anne Hathaway',
'Julia Roberts',
'Natalie Portman',
'Kate Winslet',
'Reese Witherspoon',
'Scarlett Johansson',
'Julia Roberts',
'Sandra Bullock',
'Meg Ryan',
'Lindsay Lohan'
], '2Place':['London',
'Paris',
'Rome',
'Canada',
'Scotland',
'Canada',
'Paris',
'Denmark',
'Germany',
'Denmark',
'Canada',
'London',
'Bulgaria',
'Sweden',
'Denmark',
'Brazil',
'London',
'Paris',
'Queensland',
'Qatar'], 'Document_Source': ['A','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']   })
```

For an example of expected output,

`Dead poet society and  Before sunrise: 2` means "Dead poet society" and "Before sunrise" occurs together in two document sources. ("Dead poet society" and "Before sunrise" are two titles.)

Code I am using:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
sample_df = pd.read_excel('sample_docu1.xlsx')
k=sample_df.groupby(['Document_Source','Title']).count()
print( '{}'.format(k))
```

Output I got:

```
                                                       Name  \
Title                                              A beautiful mind   
Document_Source                                                       
Agha-Hossein, M. M., El-Jouzi, S., Elmualim, A....              NaN   
Al Horr, Y., Arif, M., Kaushik, A., Mazroei, A....              1.0   
Altomonte, S., & Schiavon, S. (2013). Occupant ...              NaN   
Andelin, M., Sarasoja, A. L., Ventovuori, T., &...              NaN   
Armitage, L., & Murugan, A. (2013). The human g...              NaN   
Armitage, L., Murugan, A., & Kato, H. (2011). G...              NaN   
Azar, E., Nikolopoulou, C., & Papadopoulos, S. ...              1.0   
Baharum, M. R., & Pitt, M. (2009). Determining ...              NaN   
Baird, G. (2011). Did that building feel good f...              NaN   
Baird, G., & Penwell, J. (2012). Designers’ int...              NaN   
Baird, G., & Thompson, J. (2012). Lighting cond...              NaN  
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Expected output:

```
Dead poet society   Before sunrise  2
Dead poet society   Finding Dory    0
Dead poet society   Blood diamond   2
Dead poet society   A beautiful mind    0
Dead poet society   The longest ride    1
Dead poet society   Marley and me   1
Dead poet society   Remember me 0
Dead poet society   Inception   0
Dead poet society   Gone with the wind  0
Dead poet society   Midnight in Paris   1
Dead poet society   Mean girls  1
Dead poet society   Butterfly effect    0
Dead poet society   Letters to Juliet   0
Dead poet society   Pretty woman    0
Dead poet society   My Best Friend's Wedding    0
Dead poet society   The pursuit of happiness    0
Dead poet society   Dear john   0
Dead poet society   There's Something About Mary    0
Before sunrise  Finding Dory    0
Before sunrise  Blood diamond   2
Before sunrise  A beautiful mind    1
Before sunrise  The longest ride    1
Before sunrise  Marley and me   0
Before sunrise  Remember me 0
Before sunrise  Inception   0
Before sunrise  Gone with the wind  1
Before sunrise  Midnight in Paris   1
Before sunrise  Mean girls  1
Before sunrise  Butterfly effect    0
Before sunrise  Letters to Juliet   0
Before sunrise  Pretty woman    0
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: use `to_dict` to create a reproducible df. Give expected output to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Can you use `df.head(30).to_dict()` to provide some data?

Comment: I have provided the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

comb = df.groupby(['Document_Source'])["Title"].apply(
           lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in combinations(x, 2)]
       ).sum()
result = Counter(comb)
```

We use `combinations` to create pair of movies. Do counting with `Counter`.

`df.groupby(['Document_Source'])["Title"]` groups the data by `Document_Source` column and select the `Title` series.

Then, we use `apply` that functions on each group of the data. For each group, we use the `combinations(x, 2)` to get pairs of values. Note that we do sort the values given by `combinations(x, 2)` and make it a tuple with

```
f = lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in combinations(x, 2)]
# b = ["A", "B", "C"]
# f(b)
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

After the `apply` function, each group will have a list of tuples.

```
3Docu_Source
A    [(Before sunrise, Dead poet society), (Dead po...
B    [(A beautiful mind, Blood diamond), (A beautif...
C    [(Marley and me, The longest ride), (Blood dia...
D    [(Inception, Remember me), (Remember me, The l...
E    [(Dead poet society, Gone with the wind), (Bef...
Name: 0Title, dtype: object
```

We use `sum()` at the end because we want to aggregrate all list of tuples from each group. Using OP's data, we get a list of tuples.

```
[('Before sunrise', 'Dead poet society'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'Finding Dory'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'Dead poet society'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Finding Dory'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Blood diamond'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'Finding Dory'),
 ('A beautiful mind', 'Blood diamond'),
 ('A beautiful mind', 'Before sunrise'),
 ('A beautiful mind', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Blood diamond'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Marley and me', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'Marley and me'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'Marley and me'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Blood diamond', 'Dead poet society'),
 ('Inception', 'Remember me'),
 ('Remember me', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Inception', 'The longest ride'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'Gone with the wind'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Gone with the wind'),
 ('Gone with the wind', 'Midnight in Paris'),
 ('Gone with the wind', 'Mean girls'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Dead poet society'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'Midnight in Paris'),
 ('Dead poet society', 'Mean girls'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Midnight in Paris'),
 ('Before sunrise', 'Mean girls'),
 ('Mean girls', 'Midnight in Paris')]
```

`Counter` counts the occurances of each pairs.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain this line "comb = df.groupby(['Document_Source'])["Title"].apply(
           lambda x: [tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in combinations(x, 2)]
       ).sum()"

Comment: @SanchariGhosh if you added data, as I mentioned in the comment, I could then use the data to explain it to you and future audience.

Comment: What data you need?

Comment: If I want to have the result in a list format what changes should I make? Also I want to include all the pairs, i.e., for pairs having no common Docu_Source, it will show 0.

Comment: @SanchariGhosh sorry that I am busy these days, cannot help :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, which I find more intuitive. One main difference is my results dictionary uses `frozenset`, so the keys are not order dependent, i.e. `result[frozenset({'A', 'B'})]` = `result[frozenset({'B', 'A'})]`.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def paircalc(a, b):
    a_sources = set(df.loc[df.Title == a, 'Document_Source'])
    b_sources = set(df.loc[df.Title == b, 'Document_Source'])
    return len(a_sources & b_sources)

result = defaultdict(int)

for comb in combinations(set(df.Title), 2):
    result[frozenset(comb)] = paircalc(*comb)

# defaultdict(int,
#             {frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Marley and me'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Finding Dory'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'The longest ride'}): 1,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Remember me'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Gone with the wind'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Mean girls'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'A beautiful mind', 'Dead poet society'}): 0,
# ...
#              frozenset({'Before sunrise', 'Dead poet society'}): 2,
#              frozenset({'Blood diamond', 'Dead poet society'}): 2,
#              frozenset({'Inception', 'Midnight in Paris'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'Before sunrise', 'Midnight in Paris'}): 1,
#              frozenset({'Blood diamond', 'Midnight in Paris'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'Before sunrise', 'Inception'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'Blood diamond', 'Inception'}): 0,
#              frozenset({'Before sunrise', 'Blood diamond'}): 2})
```

Comment: Not getting the desired output. Please explain what you have done here.

Comment: `paircalc` calculates number of common sources for a single pair.. then for each combination i call paircalc. The results I have above match yours. Why is the output not desired?